# How to deal with multiple aspect ratios

Tags: android, ios, 2d, resolution, aspect-ratio

I'm developing a 2D puzzle like game. I want to target all iOS devices (iphone 4+ ,ipad 2+ and retinas) and as much android devices as possible. The problem is as you already guessed with resolutions and aspect ratios. How to deal with it, and what are the best practices. please share your experience and best approaches with this problem. My approach is , I'm building for 3:4 (the game is in portrait mode) aspect ratio with ipad retina resolution images and using orthographic camera. for different aspect ratios i resize orthographic camera , and as expected I get black bars at the top and bottom . aka pillarbox. so I'll just resize (scale Y) the main scene. (drop everything in an empty gameObject and scale it up). or add 2nd camera to deal with this black bars. **But I need the best and the most correct way to deal with this problem , what's the best practices for 2D game development when targeting multiple resolutions,aspect ratios. I've searched the net and forum but couldn't find the CORRECT WAY.**

Comment: which platform you are using for make 2d game ?

Comment: unity  2D http://unity3d.com/

Comment: Ok,
if you are using unity then we can use as some fix ratio for devices.



You can make puzzle game then set manually component means your button position (X,Y position)


Before that first fix one ration for example 800x1280 or 480x800 or 768x1024 or 1600x2456 but default most using 800x1280


after that you can set your button position as aspect width and height.


Example;

int positionX = width*0.2f;

int positionY = height*0.5f;